# Html Tab in database

Tags: html

if i have a tab in a `<pre> TABHERE </pre>` tag, and then store all the information inside of the `<pre>` tag in a database. when i attempt to display the stuff from the database would the tab still exist?

Comment: What is tab? I guess you have to just make sure that html should be well escaped for parsing for display

Comment: If a tree fell in the forest...

Comment: press your tab key to see what a tab is? its a 'long space'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your database does something weird with tabs, it should return it exactly as you put it in. Then, html will display the tab as a tab as long as it is inside another `<pre>` tag when you go to display it. If you have a tab character in your html source thats not in a `<pre>` tag (or other tag that preserves whitespace) then it will be rendered as a space.